# Java - TileBased RTS Game - creating ResourceField as a DataStructure from Map

Tags: java

I try to implement a method which gets an ArrayList of Resources like wood and create small groups of Resources as parts of the map I can use in order to create "resourceFields". So lets say i got a 100x100 sized tilemap. On the tilemap there are lets say 1000 trees randomly or fixed placed on the map. The method should iterate over all the wood resources and put resources, which are placed in a group, store in a class named ResourceField.

So far I tried to loop over the resourceList and get one resource out of the List. After I get all the neighbours (its a vector of Nodes with a resourceattribute on it) an get the resource. I got the idea to check the surrounding resources of the start resource until there are no more Nodes with a resource on it and then add these Nodes with resources to a templist. After I create a resourcefield and give the created templist to the resourcefield in the constructor. I repeat that until the resourceList is empty.

The problem is, how do I have to go on after I get the neighbours in order to get the other neighbours. I thought about recursive method, but i need the complete tempList in order to overgive it to the resourcefield constructor and if i call the method recursively theres allways a new list created and the old one isnt stored.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to implement a fllod-fill algo to identify clusters of resources in your map. Remember, recursion can lead to stack overflow errors if the recursion depth becomes too large.

Comment: Flood fill? Are there any pseudo codes?

Comment: Well, let me try putting it here:

Comment: Please check the answer which isn't really one. Couldn't put it here as a comment

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since I could not put all this in comment, I decided to put is as an answer.

It seems like you’re trying to implement a flood-fill algorithm to identify clusters of resources on your map.
Here is a simple way I would do that:

- Create an empty list to store ResourceField objects
- Iterate over each tile in the map
- If the tile contains a resource and is not already part of a ResourceField, create a new ResurceField and add the tile to it
- Use a recursive function to explore the neighboring tiles. It a neighbor contains the same resource and is not already part of a ResourceField, add it to the current ResourceField and explore recursively its neighbors
- Add the ResourceField to your list

Some pseudo code:

```java
List<ResourceField> resourceFields = new ArrayList<>();

for (Tile tile : tiles) {
    if (tile.hasResource() && !tile.isPartOfResourceField()) {
        ResourceField resourceField = new ResourceField();
        explore(tile, resourceField);
        resourceFields.add(resourceField);
    }
}

void explore(Tile tile, ResourceField resourceField) {
    if (!tile.hasResource() || tile.isPartOfResourceField()) {
        return;
    }

    resourceField.add(tile);
    tile.setPartOfResourceField(true);

    for (Tile neighbor : tile.getNeighbors()) {
        explore(neighbor, resourceField);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. I guess i get along with this.

Comment: Thats exactly what i wanted thanks again

Comment: Glad that I helped. You can accept this answer if it helped so that others can find it too.

Comment: I got another question according to this topic. Its again about clustering. I got a fisher who has an area arround his fishercottage where he can gather fish. Im about trying to make the fish resource renewable by putting fish food in the water. I just thought about taking the fish resources which are already there, but theres more space in the field. How cann I calculate the tiles close to the shore in order to put some fish food there and let the fish grow up again after the resource is gathered completely?

Comment: One way to calculate the tiles close to the shore where you can put fish food is to use a breadth-first search algorithm (BFS)

Comment: I read in the topic. What is the termination condition in my case? When there are no more tiles exploreable and i take the last nodes of the search?

Comment: The termination condition is when there are no more tiles to explore, e.g: when the queue is empty. At that point, you have visited all the water tiles that are reachable from the fisher’s cottage and are within the specified distance from the shore. You can put fish food on all the tiles that meet your criteria for being "close enough to the shore".

Comment: ok thx. And i got another question, but it maybe has no more to do with the topic of the question. I got a isometric tileselection problem. I read a lot forum posts about that, but nothing fits for me. So my diamond isometric grid has in the top corner the point 0,0. Is there any formula which can convert the mouse screen coords to iso world coords? In order to do tileselection. So far i had no camera implemented and i got offset problems which i havent recognized.